# How do I view a horizontal Gallery of my Android Gallery in app development?

Tags: android

I couldn't seem to find this specific issue anywhere and was just wondering about a specific problem.

In my app, I take pictures of shirts, pants, and shoes and then store them into separate directories in the Android Gallery.

On the main screen of my app, I'm trying to make it where there are essentially three horizontal rows that have scrollable galleries for each directory. In the top one, I want to be able to scroll through shirt images from the Android Gallery directory, in the middle should be pants from its corresponding directory and in the bottom will be shoes with its corresponding directory.

I'm just trying to figure out how I can set this up. I have the camera features already set up and it is saving the images in the correct directories. At this point, I can't seem to wrap my head around how I can scroll through the images in each horizontal row, with images coming in and out of the screen on the right and left sides. The 3-image column, of course, will align the three selected images.

Thanks a ton!

-Matt

EDIT: Here is the code if it helps:

Main Activity Snippet: [LINK](http://pastebin.com/18DqPS4Q)

ImageAdapter: [LINK](http://pastebin.com/jg127uvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager and set the orientation in the manager as Horizontal

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

For more information check [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#HORIZONTAL) and [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

You cab use something like this for picasso

> @Override public void OnBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
>
> String imageUrl = "abc.com/a/b/c.png";    Uri uri = Uri.parsr(imageUrl);
>      Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(viewHolder.imageView);
>
> }

Comment: Ok awesome, thanks!! Do you know how I would access my Gallery items from their directories?

Comment: You can use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to download and cache the images and them retrieve from SD Card with recycler view.

Comment: Updated the answer with a small example.

Comment: I'm still working on it. It is for my app dev. class so I have been procrastinating. I will 100% make sure I follow up with this, though!

Comment: I'm having trouble with NullPointerExceptions. I've implemented an adapter and a couple other classes based off of this tutorial: http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CFL00Ujx is the error log. I need more reputation to post more links, which is why I posted it here. I posted a couple links to source code in my main post.

Comment: looks like you have a null object being referenced in `onCreate()` method..The code you added does not help much.. Debug the app and put a breakpoint in `onCreate()` of your Activity

Comment: Thank you so much! I've implemented the RecyclerView successfully. Now I'm just working on optimization with Decorations.